# How do I translate "Alma does not eat anything unless she eats an apple" into predicate logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, predicate-logic

Dictionary:

A: _ is apple, G: _ is green, D: _ eats _, a: Alma

What I came up with:

( ∃x(Ax ∧ Dax) → ∀xDax )

If there is an apple that Alma eats, then she eats anything.

I know it's not correct, but I don't know why...

Comment: It's unclear whether you mean all things Alma eats are apples, or that the set of things she eats either contains at least one apple or else is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it is a somewhatcomplicated way of saying that she eats only apples. Thus it would be:

$\forall x \: (Dax \rightarrow Ax)$

Also, given your predicate $G$, was your sentence maybe meant to mean that she only eats green apples?  In that case, it would be:

$\forall x \: (Dax \rightarrow (Ax \wedge Gx))$

**Edit**

No, I did read this incorrectly. It should be 'as long as she doesn't eat an apple, she doesn't eat anything at all'. So:

$\neg \exists x (Dax \wedge Ax) \rightarrow \neg \exists x \: Dax$

... Which is just the contrapositive of Dion's answer!  Ok, this must be right.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to write the sentence is "If Alma eats anything, she eats an apple".  You need something in your dictionary for Alma eats ___.

Comment: Would I write it like this: ( ∀xDax → ∃x(Ax ∧ Dax) )

Comment: I would not reuse $x$ as a variable.  I think your version is correct if your syntax is careful about the scope of variables, but it would be easier to read the sentence if the second bound variable were $y$.  Assuming Dax means Alma eats x this is correct.

Comment: Ya, we have to use x, we haven't gotten to using more variables.

Comment: Just noticed I had wrong meaning for D in the dictionary. yes Dax mean Alma eats x

Comment: Yes, what Ross says: read this as 'if she eats anything, it would be an apple', which can be paraphrased yet again as 'whatever she eats is an apple', or even more simply 'she eats only apples'. For that, you only need 1 variable.

Comment: @Bram28:  but she could eat an apple and something else.  I think your translation forbids that.

Comment: @RossMillikan I see: once she has eaten an apple, she may eat other things. So I read this as 'if she eats anything, then what she eats must be an apple', but it should probably read 'as long as she doesn't eat an apple, she won't eat anything at all'. I'll change my answer accordingly. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

∃x(Dax) → ∃y(Day ∧ Ay)

"If alma has eaten at least one thing, then she has eaten an apple."